# Cannot set variable in trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin, declaration

I am trying to set a variable in a trigger that is the most recent entry in the table. However, PHPMyAdmin notes there is an error at line `SET clicked_campaign_id =`. I do not see the problem here.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_user_action_click 
AFTER INSERT ON users_click FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE clicked_campaign_id int

    SET clicked_campaign_id = 
    (SELECT campaignId 
    FROM users_click 
    WHERE id = (SELECT max(id) FROM users_click));

    Update onlineportal.`campaigns`
    SET `clicks` = `clicks` + 1
    WHERE id = clicked_campaign_id;
END
```

Is there a different way to set a variable...?

Comment: Add `;`. Try: `DECLARE clicked_campaign_id int;`

Comment: that does not work either, it errors out on that line with the additional `;`

Comment: Remember to properly set the `DELIMITER` in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: @wchiquito properly set `DELIMITER`?

Comment: See [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25891743/1316440).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the DELIMITER in phpMyAdmin, as shown in the image:

[image]

Then, create the trigger:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER `tr_user_action_click` AFTER INSERT ON `users_click`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE `clicked_campaign_id` INT;

    SET `clicked_campaign_id` = 
    (SELECT `campaignId` 
    FROM `users_click`
    WHERE `id` = (SELECT max(`id`) FROM `users_click`));

    UPDATE `onlineportal`.`campaigns`
    SET `clicks` = `clicks` + 1
    WHERE `id` = `clicked_campaign_id`;
END//
```